# Should I add (prorated) $5000 tax treaty exempt in state tax report?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, international, california

I am a F1 visa Chinese student. I did 4 months intern in California in 2016, and spent the rest of the year as TA back in school in Idaho. So I have W-2 forms from both CA and ID.

Now I am confused about how to calculate the Idaho tax form 43, line 7 (idaho amounts). Wages, salaries, tips, etc. include Form(s) W-2.

Sprintax did it for me as the following method:

Idaho W2 box1 + 1042S ($5000) - non-taxable portion for ID of the tax treaty.

I have no idea how they calculated the third term above. they said tax treaty is prorated between California and Idaho.
Also, should I add the $5000? my friend in Idaho told me I should NOT add, but he just had income from Idaho.

Any idea or comments?
Thanks!